# How can I automatically set version numbers in a Makefile?

Tags: makefile, debian, packaging, rpmbuild

I have a Makefile which I use to launch package building tools. I have my `debian` files and `rpm` build files in the same directory and I can just say `build deb` or `build rpm` and the packages build.

Right now when I update the package I am taring the source where necessary, and updating the `Makefile` with new version numbers manually. I want to automate the version numbers because it is tedious but I am not sure how to go about it.

My Makefile looks like this:

```
# a list of tools we depend on and must install if they're missing
DEBTOOLS=/usr/bin/debuild-pbuilder
RPMBUILD=/usr/bin/rpmbuild

# convenience target for "make deb"
deb: my-packages_1.1.1_all.deb

# check for the pbuilder package
/usr/bin/debuild-pbuilder:
    apt-get -y install pbuilder

# convenience target for "make rpm".  This should acctually be strutured to depend on the RPM file as "deb" does
rpm:
    my-package-1.1.1-Public.noarch.rpm

# the target package (on Ubuntu at least)
my-package_1.0_all.deb: $(DEBTOOLS)
    cd my-package; debuild-pbuilder -us -uc

my-package-1.1-Public.noarch.rpm: $(RPMBUILD) tar-source
    cd my-package-rpm; rpmbuild -bb SPECS/my-packages.spec

tar-source:
    tar -cvzf my-packages-1.1.1.tar.gz my-package-1.1.1/
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about rpm, but for debian you can make a target that calls debchange with the -v parameter

Untested sample:

```
VERSION=`git describe`

bump-version:
            dch -v $(VERSION)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try using something like the following to get the Debian version string:

`dpkg-parsechangelog --show-field Version`

I don't know about the rpm case.